# bad m2eclipse-android-integration plugin performance

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am using [m2eclipse-android-integration](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/) version 0.2.5 (and all the required plugins) on eclipse helios. I like to use this plugin because it puts all maven dependencies in the generated apk file.

But, on each code change (save) eclipse runs in a "Building Workspace..." operation which takes really a long time. I am runnig my eclipse with `-Xmx1024m` and also generated a fresh workspace for my android project. It does not help :-(

After uninstalling the plugin a save operation also results in "Building Workspace..." but that takes just a second.

It must be possible to work with the plugin without this performance issue (and still having "Build automatically..." enabled). Does anybody know how?

Thanks Klaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the m2eclipse-android-integration plugin:

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/issues/detail?id=23

Which we're hoping to fix for the next release. Please raise any further issues with the m2eclipse-android-integration plugin here:

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/issues/entry

Comment: I was not sure if it was a plugin issue or a usage problem. Thanks for information. I have no google account (and do not like one at the moment), so I am not able to raise further issues an the site you mentioned.

Comment: Shame, users should be able to raise anonymous tickets, can't see anywhere to allow it in the project settings. You can always email me directly with issues and I'll raise them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this problem is realy tedious as it's almost impossible to use maven with android in Eclipse with those very long periods being stuck. For the time being I prefer managing libraries manually until you correct the problem.
Don't hesitate to tell when it's resolved because I will be one of the first to test it ;)

Comment: Feel free to contribute patches if you get the chance. All help gratefully received.